# WSO2 EMM GCM not working null Reference exceptions

Tags: exception, google-cloud-messaging, wso2-iot

I am using WSO2 EMM version 1.1.0

After registrering some Android devices all was going well but after 
I try to setup GCM with Android , I got some exception in the carbonlog

what can I do ?

```html
 TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-02-05 13:32:09,473] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (gcm#7) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (gcm#7)
 at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
 at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)


Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (gcm#7)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.gcm_21._c_anonymous_2(gcm:7)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.gcm_21.call(gcm)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wso2.mobile.gcm.GCMServerBridge.sendDataViaGCM(GCMServerBridge.java:61)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to find the exact issue without the code as its impossible to debug.  But you can look over [this sample source code](https://github.com/wso2/emm-agent-android) that integrates the capabilities of WSO2 EMM with the GCM. Check to see the Manifest file if you are missing some permissions or referencing some variable that has been declared but not been initialized.

Follow [this](https://blog.udemy.com/java-null-pointer-exception/) and [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/06/common-cause-of-javalangnullpointerexce.html) article to see is there any cause that matches in your code for having the Null pointer Exception.\

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: I am afraid you miss understand my troubles. The exception are on the server side WSO2 EMM not on the android agent . I have just put my sender ids and key on the Android settings.

Comment: I am sorry no , putting WSO2-EMM in GCM configuration broke WSO2.